# How to download a gridview into pdf in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview

I have one Grid View called GridView1. This grid view i want to download in PDF.
For this i tried following code.

PDF file is downloading but not opening. I am getting error i.e Adobe Reader can't open this file.

Please help me.

```
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from info", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView grdview = new GridView();
    GridView1.DataBind();

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";  
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: Use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good way to output an asp.net, C# GridView into a PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192942/what-is-a-good-way-to-output-an-asp-net-c-sharp-gridview-into-a-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Infact PDF files have its own format, however GridView.RenderControl renders HTML.
You have to use a third-party PDF creation library which will convert HTML to PDF, or to create PDF in another way.

Comment: Is it possible to export gridview in pdf without using third party component?

Comment: There are some possibilities, using iTextSharp. See http://highoncoding.com/Articles/483_Exporting_GridView_to_PDF_Document.aspx